# Count occurrences based on multiple conditions pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame named 'table':

[image]

The 'type' columns has 3 categories : 1, 2 and 3

How can I count the occurrence of each id in 'topic_id' column based on the 3 categories of the 'type' column, in short, how many times one topic_id appears for each categories 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Do you need `print (pd.crosstab(df.topic_id, df.type))` ?

Comment: the result should be stored in a new dataframe which has topic_id, type_1, type_2, type_3 as columns @jezrael. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'topic_id':[1,2,3,1,2],
                   'type':[1,2,3,1,2]})

print (df)
   topic_id  type
0         1     1
1         2     2
2         3     3
3         1     1
4         2     2

print (pd.crosstab(df.topic_id, df.type))
type      1  2  3
topic_id         
1         2  0  0
2         0  2  0
3         0  0  1
```

Comment: you are my savior @jezrael :D. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad can help you. And one small advice [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) - then get a lot of downvotes. The best is sample data, desired output and what you try.

Comment: @ThànhĐạt: please also [refrain from urgent begging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) - your audience is mostly made up of volunteers. They will answer questions they find interesting, and only at their leisure. If you need to set deadlines then you need a freelancer.